# Parse protobuf response from adb shell am instrument, to json or xml

Tags: android, adb, protocol-buffers, android-espresso, spoon

I want to get test results in some structure that I can work with the command `adb shell am instrument`.
From adb shell am help menu:

```
instrument
   -m: Write output as protobuf to stdout (machine readable)
```

and the response looks something like this:

```
?"?
7
class.com.example.myfirstapp.ExampleInstrumentedTest


current

idAndroidJUnitRunner


numtests
:
stream0
com.example.myfirstapp.ExampleInstrumentedTest:

testtest1
??C"?
7
class.com.example.myfirstapp.ExampleInstrumentedTest


current

idAndroidJUnitRunner


numtests


stream.

testtest1*??C--------- beginning of main
```

Is there a way to parse this to xml or json?

---

**UPDATE**

My goal was to receive the Android test results from the execution. For that I found an open source tool - Spoon - that does it (among other things)
https://github.com/square/spoon

After executing the test with spoon, the result XML file is in `spoon-output/junit-reports` directory.

Comment: Protobuf is a binary format. So first you should pipe the output to a file and then use an hex editor to check the content. As a first test you can use the online tool [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Protobuf_Decode('',false,false)) to decode the response. If this works you have valid protobuf data.

Comment: @Robert what I can do with the decoded data? Is there a way to turn it into xml or json?

Comment: Protobuf data only contains the structure but no field names and so on. So if you would need a matching proto definition to convert it to something readable, otherwise you just get numbers as field names and some objects may not be correctly decoded. Depending on the data you may be able to convert it to JSON but Protobuf is in general more powerful than JSON (e.g. repeatable fields). Just look at the decoded structure and you will see what works for you.

Comment: @Robert I saw the decoded data and as you said the field names are just numbers. So the question is what can I do with this? If I don't have the schema that used to generate this protobuf? Why adb returns protobuf format if a user can't deserialize it without the .proto file that used to create it...?

Comment: Android/AOSP is open source so the proto definition can be found easily: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/cmds/am/proto/instrumentation_data.proto This blog post is also related https://malinskiy.medium.com/android-am-instrument-proto-test-result-architecture-review-790652b6a202